# How to assign new values from lapply to new column in dataframes in list

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I have a list of dataframes. I want to perform an operation on columns of the dataframes and then create a new column in the dataframes with the resulting new column.

```
a <- data.frame(c(1,2,3), c(2,3,4))
b <- data.frame(c(7,8,9), c(5,6,2))
l <- list(a, b)
lapply(l, function(x) x[,2]*2)
```

What I want is for `4 6 8` and `10 12 4` to be assigned to the third columns of the first and second dataframes, respectively.

This does not seem to work:

```
lapply(l, function(x) x[,2]*2 -> x$new)
```

Comment: You have to return the data frame: `lapply(l, function(x) { x[,2]*2 -> x$new; x })`.

Comment: @lukeA Could you please clarify the syntax of what is in the { }'s?

Comment: The only thing, which is different from yours, is `return(x)` - or short: `x`. As the function contains not only one command, but two (seperated by `;` or by a linefeed), you got to wrap it in `{`...`}`. `x` returns the data frame after you added `new `to it.

Comment: Got it! Now I can just assign it back to `l` and be good. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `cbind` to add the new column to the data frames in the list:

```
lapply(l, function(x) cbind(x, x[,2]*2))
# [[1]]
#   c.1..2..3. c.2..3..4. x[, 2] * 2
# 1          1          2          4
# 2          2          3          6
# 3          3          4          8
# 
# [[2]]
#   c.7..8..9. c.5..6..2. x[, 2] * 2
# 1          7          5         10
# 2          8          6         12
# 3          9          2          4
```