# Using Apply or Vectorize to apply custom function to a dataframe

Tags: r, vectorization, apply, lapply

I am attempting to apply a custom function that calls components of that dataframe to do a calculation. I have made a trivial example below because my actual problem is very hard to make a reproducible example. In the below example I want to have the first two columns be added together to create a third column which is the sum of them. Below is an example I found online that gets close to what I want:

```
celebrities=data.frame(name=c("Andrew","matt","Dany","Philip","John","bing","Monica"),
                       age=c(28,23,49,29,38,23,29),
                       income=c(25.2,10.5,11,21.9,44,11.5,45))
f=function(x,output){
  name=x[1]
  income=x[3]
  cat(name,income,"\n")
}
apply(celebrities,1,f)
```

But when I try to take it and apply mathematical function it doesn't work:

```
  f2=function(x,output){
  age=x[2]
  income=x[3]
  sum(age,income)
}
apply(celebrities,1,f2)
```

In essence what I need is for apply to take a dataset, go through every row of that dataset using the values in that row as inputs into the function and add a third column to the dataset with the results of the function. Please let me know how I can clarify this question if needed. I have referred to the questions below, but they don't seem to work for me.

[Apply a function to every row of a matrix or a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236368/apply-a-function-to-every-row-of-a-matrix-or-a-data-frame)

[How to assign new values from lapply to new column in dataframes in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28820505/how-to-assign-new-values-from-lapply-to-new-column-in-dataframes-in-list)

[Call apply-like function on each row of dataframe with multiple arguments from each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059076/call-apply-like-function-on-each-row-of-dataframe-with-multiple-arguments-from-e)

Comment: When you use `apply` on a `data.frame`, it is converted to a `matrix` for the processing. If any of the columns (of the processed frame) are `character`, the all columns are converted to `character`, defeating any math operations. Though I tend to discourage `apply` with frames, if you must then make sure that you only use a portion of it, something like `apply(celebrities[c("age","income")], 1, sum)`.

Comment: You could try using something from `library(plyr)` such as `adply` or `aaply` (depending on what you want the output format to be like) which don't coerce all columns to `character`

Comment: I believe `dplyr` now has a `rowwise` function that can help you do what you're looking for.  E.g., `library(dplyr) ; celebrities %>% rowwise %>% mutate(new_var = f(var1, var2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the particular task requested it could be

```
celebrities$newcol <- with(celebrities, age + income)
```

The `+` function is inherently vectorized. Using `apply` with `sum` is inefficient. Using `apply` could have been greatly simplified by omitting the first column because that would avoid the coercion to a character matrix caused by the first column.

```
 celebrities$newcol <- apply(celebrities[-1], function(x) sum(x) )
```

That way you would avoid coercing the vectors to "character" and then needing to coerce back the formerly-numeric columns to `numeric`. Using `sum` inside apply does get around the fact that sum is not vectorized, but it's an example of inefficient R coding.

You get automatic vectorization if the "inner" algorithm can be constructed completely from vectorized functions: the Math and Ops groups being the usual components. See `?Ops`. Otherwise, you may need to use `mapply` or `Vectorize`.

Answer (score 1):

Taking hints from @r2evans and @user2738526 I have made the modification to your function.
Explicitly convert numbers to numeric.
The below code snippet works for your case:

```
f2=function(x,output){
  age=as.numeric(x[2])
  income=as.numeric(x[3])
  sum(age,income)
}
apply(celebrities,1,f2)

[1] 53.2 33.5 60.0 50.9 82.0 34.5 74.0
```

Comment: I'm not downvoting because did solve the problem after identifying the errors in the original, but you should understand that this is rather ugly R coding and would not be a good example for others to emulate. `r2evans` gave better advice and you seemed to ignore it.

Comment: @42- I dont like my solution either, it is rather inefficient, cumbersome and what not but I thought if the OP had any other numerical function than `sum`. r2evans gave a better solution I agree. The original question doesn't need `apply` at all

Comment: I'll delete it if it is not worth keeping it up here

Comment: It could be useful as a basis for explaining _why_ you should be searching for other strategies before using `apply`. I'd upvote it if it were improved in that direction.

Comment: @42- sure I'll do that. I'd need to read up a bit more to improve it in the direction suggested

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
library(dplyr)
celebrities=data.frame(name=c("Andrew","matt","Dany","Philip","John","bing","Monica"),
                       age=c(28,23,49,29,38,23,29),
                       income=c(25.2,10.5,11,21.9,44,11.5,45)) 

celebrities %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(age_plus_income = sum(age, income))
```

(Obviously, for summing two columns, you'd be better off using `mutate(celebrities, age_plus_income = age + income)`, but I assume your real example uses a more complicated function.)